# How to implement object serialization like console.log

Tags: javascript, console

I want to implement a logger function. It needs serialization of an object or type. And if I using `toString`, it returns `[object xxx]`, if using JSON.stringfy, it returns a json string but ugly. the `console.log` print very nice. Is there any way can I implement a `logger` like this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's what you are looking for, but `JSON.stringify` takes more optional parameters to make it more attractive

```js
const a = JSON.stringify({first:1,second:2,object:{array:[1,2]}}, null, 4); // indent with 4 spaces

console.log(a);
```